# How to get the real number of bytes when i use read function of ifstream

Tags: c++, io

The code:

```
ifstream in("a.jpg",ios:in|ios:binary);
char data[1024];
in.read(data,1024);
```

How can i know the real number of bytes that *read*function read?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/

Comment: [Here's another reference you can search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `gcount`, something like this:

```
std::streamsize bytes_read = in.gcount();
```